# Img div and txt(h3) align

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to align these elements:(the div with the class imgBoxPost and the h3.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="imgBoxPost">
        <img src="img/<?php echo $_SESSION['image']; ?>" class="imgFitInTheBox imgRadius">
    </div>
    <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></h3>
</div>
```

In the imgboxPost I have the width and the height of that div.

Comment: Which layout you want to align ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them inline-blocks:
(If you want to align them vertically centered, add `vertical-align: middle;` to that CSS rule)

```css
.panel-body .imgBoxPost,
.panel-body h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="imgBoxPost">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/60x90/fb5" class="imgFitInTheBox imgRadius">
    </div>
    <h3>This is an H3 element</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add twitter bootstrap in you code download bootstrap from here http://getbootstrap.com/
then add bootstrap classes in your code

```
<div class="panel-body row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="imgBoxPost col-md-6" >
        <img src="img/<?php echo $_SESSION['image']; ?>" class="imgFitInTheBox imgRadius">
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6"> <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></h3></div>
</div>
</div>
```